# Calling dateNow() with XALAN

Tags: java, xml, xslt

am using XSL which is being called by JAVA method, I have tried  to fix it by giving absolute path of a class but I don't think it will work because I didn't find anywhere calling a method in XSL using absolute class path so am trying by keeping in the server environment.here is my code,i have given class path and i have called method also .. but am not getting the proper output. Is this the correct way to call a method?

```
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
        xmlns:datetime="java:com.ibm.date"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xalan"
        version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template name="RootToAcknowledgeInventoryRequirement">
    <xsl:param name="Root" />
    <xsl:variable name="PromiseHeader" select="$Root/PromiseHeader" />
    <xsl:variable name="today" select="datetime:dateNow()" />
    <xsl:variable name="OrganizationCode">
      <xsl:value-of select="$PromiseHeader/@OrganizationCode" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <_inv:AcknowledgeInventoryRequirement releaseID="">
      <_wcf:ApplicationArea>
        <oa:CreationDateTime xsi:type="udt:DateTimeType">
          <xsl:value-of select="datetime:dateNow()" />
        </oa:CreationDateTime>
      </_wcf:ApplicationArea>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. On SO, we ask questions. Please *edit* your post and provide a specific question with the exact problem you are having, and also provide a more descriptive title.

Comment: i need to know how to call a method and how to give class path in XSL?

Comment: There are many docs and tutorials out there. At least, you'll know where to start....

Comment: i Have got little idea by reading this http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch17s03.html but still am not able fix it..

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned XLAN processor, its version is XSLT 1.0.

So by default it doesn't possess any date-time function that brings it a current datetime value.

It is XSLT 2.0 that supports

```
<xsl:value-of  select="current-dateTime()"/>
<xsl:value-of  select="current-date()"/>
<xsl:value-of  select="current-time()"/>
```

you should go with Machael Kay's Saxon latest version for that.

Now for work around, EXSLT has been into good practice:

Download code from [this link](http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html), copy `date.xsl` to your xsl file's location. Import it in your xsl.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" 
    extension-element-prefixes="date"
    ...>

    <xsl:import href="date.xsl" />

    <xsl:template match="//root">
       <xsl:value-of select="date:date-time()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

solution 2: Pass Datetime value as param to XSL. Use it as variable wherever required.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur response its really helped lot for me to go further Thank you